# Checking Bluetooth status (on/off) in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, iphone, bluetooth, xamarin.ios

I am looking for a function that gets the status of the devices Bluetooth so I can tell the app users if it is on or off.

Current code keeps saying the Bluetooth is off even though it is on. Any help and guidance is appreciated!

```
public bool CheckBluetoothStatus()
        {
            bool status;

            if (state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn)
            {
                status = true;
                bluetoothEnabledLbl.Text = "Bluetooth enabled";
                bluetoothEnabledAdviceLbl.Text = "Consider turning Bluetooth off if not in use or check to see if all connected devices are recognisable";

                return status;
            }
            else
            {
                status = false;
                bluetoothEnabledLbl.Text = "Bluetooth not enabled";

                return status;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi , welcome to SO ! Your code has no problem , you need to notice that not running in a simulator device . And check the permission whether added in `info.plist` .

Comment: Where does `state` come from?

Comment: Hi ,have you solved it ? If answer be helpful , remember to mark or vote up it when you have time .

Answer (score 0):

There are two **points** need to pay attention when developing **Xamarin iOS bluetooth** application.

- **First** ,you need to run it in a physical device , can not testing bluetooth function in a simulator device . If that , you will always get follow console log with shared code :

> 2020-02-28 13:32:38.310442+0800 AppIOSBluetooth[36757:5394891] Bluetooth not enabled

- **Second** , you need to add permission for bluetooth application in `info.plist` file .When first running app , it will show permission popup window .

[image]

However , in `info.plist` , you can add the permission of Bluetooth easily as follow and will forget another most important permission :

```
<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
<string>Add BlueTooth Peripheral Permission</string>
```

That's not enough for Bluetooth . You also need to add another permission :

```
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>use Bluetooth</string>
```

In addition , there is [an offical API doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/corebluetooth?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12#remarks) about using Bluetooth in Xamarin iOS you can have a look .

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    myDel = new MySimpleCBCentralManagerDelegate();
    var myMgr = new CBCentralManager(myDel, DispatchQueue.CurrentQueue);
}

public class MySimpleCBCentralManagerDelegate : CBCentralManagerDelegate
{
    override public void UpdatedState(CBCentralManager mgr)
    {
        if (mgr.State == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bluetooth is available");
            //Passing in null scans for all peripherals. Peripherals can be targeted by using CBUIIDs
            CBUUID[] cbuuids = null;
            mgr.ScanForPeripherals(cbuuids); //Initiates async calls of DiscoveredPeripheral
                                                //Timeout after 30 seconds
            var timer = new Timer(30 * 1000);
            timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => mgr.StopScan();
        }
        else
        {
            //Invalid state -- Bluetooth powered down, unavailable, etc.
            System.Console.WriteLine("Bluetooth is not available");
        }
    }
    public override void DiscoveredPeripheral(CBCentralManager central, CBPeripheral peripheral, NSDictionary advertisementData, NSNumber RSSI)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Discovered {0}, data {1}, RSSI {2}", peripheral.Name, advertisementData, RSSI);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this and if nothing changes it can be because of device version :

```
private CBCentralManagerState state; 
public bool CheckBluetoothStatus()
    {
        bool status;

        if (state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn)
        {
            status = true;
            bluetoothEnabledLbl.Text = "Bluetooth enabled";
            bluetoothEnabledAdviceLbl.Text = "Consider turning Bluetooth off if not in use or check to see if all connected devices are recognisable";

        }
        else
        {
            status = false;
            bluetoothEnabledLbl.Text = "Bluetooth not enabled";

        }
            return status;
    }
```